# How to change font type in tabularx

Tags: fonts, tabularx

How to change one table column in other font type, I need to change all left column. For example from normal to Consolas font. My `tabularx`:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|} \hline
      {\bf wow} &  {\bf nice}  \\ \hline 
      cool &  yey!  \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please read [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

For this you need to column type add `>{\ttfamily}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% <-- Only show only table.
                                             % Don't use in +real document! 
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\ttfamily}l|X|}
\hline
\textbf{wow}    &  \textbf{nice}  \\ \hline
cool            &  yey!  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}\end{document}
```

(if you with "Console" type mean Typewriter's font).

**Edit:** Regarding your comment about For centering of column heads: fpor this you have more possibilities:

- use  `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{head text>}}`
- add `makecell` package and use macro `thead{.....}`. For font in it you need to redefine the `theadfont`: `\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}`.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\ttfamily}l|X|}
\hline
\thead{wow}    &  \thead{nice}  \\ \hline
cool           &  yey!  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did everything like this, but it is error. Which package I should use with `>{\italic}` ?

Comment: @Mantas: There is no `\italic`... you probably want `\itshape`.

Comment: nice :) Okey now back to Consolas font, maybe you can tell me how it is called in latex?

Comment: Typewriter? See, if they look as you like to have.

Comment: @zarko Thanks. Maybe you could advice how to make my head line centered? only headline?(in tabular)

Comment: See edit of my answer